# SwiftUI Toolbar button tap area intermittently out of alignment

Tags: ios, swiftui

My application uses .toolbar containing Multiple Buttons and one Menu element.  I am intermittently, but often having issues where the toolbar button are only responding to touch immediately below the button label.  I was finally able to visualize what the application was doing by monitoring the view hierarchy.  It appears that the issue may go away when I remove the menu, but the menu is absolutely necessary.  Looking for insight on how to prevent this. Please help.

Disclaimer:  I am new to SwiftUI and optimizing/cleaning up code as I go. This is my first project.  Critiques are appreciated, criticism not necessary. :)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ToolbarView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var user: loggedInUser
@EnvironmentObject var viewData: apiData
@EnvironmentObject var selectedUser: showingUser
@EnvironmentObject var modes: appModes

@Binding var metricSelection: String?
@Binding var userSearchEntry: Bool
@Binding var userNotFound: Bool

@Binding var viewName: String
@Binding var viewNameEntry: Bool
@Binding var viewSelection: String
@Binding var showMessages: Bool
@Binding var showTeam: Bool
@Binding var showSettings: Bool


var body: some View {
    //        if testing {
    //            let _ = Self._printChanges()
    //       }
        HStack{
            if modes.isIphone {
                Button {
                    debugMsg(msg: "Showing settings menu")
                    showSettings = true
                }  label:  {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
                
                Button {
                    debugMsg(msg: "Showing teams menu")
                    showTeam = true
                }  label:  {
                    Image(systemName: "person.3.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
            }
            //Home Button
            Button {
                debugMsg(msg: "Showing messages/home")
                if modes.isIphone {
                    showMessages = true
                } else {
                    metricSelection = nil
                }
                
            }  label:  {
                Image(systemName: "newspaper.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            
        
            HStack{
                Menu {
                    Button {
                        if !modes.isEditing {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                modes.isEditing = true
                            }
                        }
                        viewNameEntry.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text("Create View")
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Disable editing of "show all"
                    let editableViews = Array(viewData.metricViews.keys).sorted().filter{view in
                        return !["show all","default"].contains(view)
                    }
                    
                    let menuViews = ["default"] + editableViews + (modes.isEditing ? [] : ["show all"])
                    
                    ForEach(menuViews, id: \.self){ key in
                        let menuKey = key as String
                        Button{
                            // MARK: CUSTOM VIEW SELECT
                            viewSelection = menuKey
                            debugMsg(msg: "View Selection Made: \(menuKey)")
                        } label : {
                            // when editing show modify/delete menu excluding "default"
                            if modes.isEditing && !["default","show all"].contains(menuKey) {
                                Menu {
                                    // MARK: CUSTOM VIEW MODIFY
                                    Button {
                                        viewSelection = menuKey
                                        debugMsg(msg: "Custom view selected for Modification: \(menuKey)")
                                        if viewData.metricViews[menuKey]!.metrics.count > 0 {
                                            metricSelection = viewData.metricViews[menuKey]!.metrics[0]
                                            debugMsg(msg: "metricSelection set to first metric in view: \(metricSelection!)")
                                        } else {
                                            metricSelection = nil
                                            debugMsg(msg: "metricSelection set to nil: \(menuKey)")
                                        }
                                        
                                    } label: {
                                        HStack(alignment: .center){
                                            Text("Modify")
                                            Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    // MARK: CUSTOM VIEW DELETE
                                        Menu {
                                            Button {
                                                debugMsg(msg: "Deletion Confirmed: \(menuKey)")
                                                deleteView(viewToDelete: menuKey) { success in
                                                    if success {
                                                        debugMsg(msg: "DB Deletion Success: \(menuKey)")
                                                        viewData.deleteView(view: menuKey) { success in
                                                            if viewSelection == menuKey {
                                                                viewSelection = "default"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                
                                            } label: {
                                                HStack{
                                                    Text("Confirm")
                                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                                }
                                            }
                                            
                                            Button {
                                                debugMsg(msg: "Deletion Cancelled: \(menuKey)")
                                            } label: {
                                                HStack{
                                                    Text("Cancel")
                                                    Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                                                }
                                            }
                                            
                                        } label: {
                                            HStack{
                                                Text("Delete")
                                                Image(systemName: "trash.circle")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    
                                } label: {
                                    Text(key.localizedCapitalized)
                                    
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                Text(key.localizedCapitalized)
                            }
                            if viewSelection == key {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease")
                    
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
            }
                
            
            
            //Edit View Button
            Button(action: {
                debugMsg(msg: "Toggling edit mode")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    modes.isEditing.toggle()
                }
                if viewSelection == "show all" {
                    viewSelection = "default"
                }
                let viewMetrics = viewData.metricViews[viewSelection]!.metrics
                var metrics = Array<String>()
                viewMetrics.forEach {
                    metrics.append($0)
                }
                if metricSelection != nil && !modes.isEditing {
                    if metrics.count == 0 {
                        debugMsg(msg: "metric count = 0 setting, metric selection to nil")
                        metricSelection = nil
                    } else if !metrics.contains(metricSelection!) {
                        debugMsg(msg: "\(metricSelection!) not in view.")
                        metricSelection = metrics[0]
                        debugMsg(msg: "reverting to first metric in view: \(metricSelection!)")
                    } else {
                        debugMsg(msg: "\(metricSelection!) in view.  No change")
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: modes.isEditing ? "gauge" : "gauge.badge.plus")
                    .foregroundColor(modes.isEditing ? .blue : .secondary)
                    //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            
            //Sign Out Button
            Button {
                debugMsg(msg: "Signing out")
                viewSelection = "default"
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    user.reset()
                    selectedUser.reset()
                    viewData.reset()
                    modes.isLoading = false
                }
                
            } label: {
                CachedAsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(userImageUrl)\(user.attuid)")) { image in
                    image.resizable()
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 2))
                } placeholder: {
                    CachedAsyncImage(url: URL(string: "\(userImageUrl)\(user.attuid)")) { image in
                        image.resizable()
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 2))
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width:30, height: 35)
            }
            
            //Emulate Button
            Button {
                debugMsg(msg: "Toggling user search")
                userSearchEntry.toggle()
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.questionmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
    
}


func deleteView(viewToDelete: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        modes.isLoading.toggle()
    }
    debugMsg(msg: "Posting delete payload to DB: \(viewToDelete)")
    let payload = deleteViewPayload(view: viewToDelete, uid: user.attuid)
    APIClient.deleteView(payload:payload) { result, error in
        let jsonData = result!
        let status = jsonData["status"] as! String
        debugMsg(msg: "DB Response: \(status) - \(viewToDelete)")
    }
    modes.isLoading.toggle()
    completion(true)
}

}
```

[image: View Hierarchy - Correct]

[image: View Hierarchy - Incorrect]

Comment: Without a [mre], this will be difficult if not impossible to debug.